# ngOnDestroy is not called (ngFor and Async Pipe)

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm building a realtime map with Angular 4, Openlayers and Firebase as my backend database.

I'm also using `AngularFire2` to comunicate my Angular app with `firebase`.

For displaying the features in the map, I wrapped [`ol.Feature Class`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Feature.html) in a Component so that I can take advantage of Angular Features.

```
<app-vector-layer-feature
    *ngFor = "let feature of (observableFeatureList | sliceObservableList:0:MAX_FEATURES) | async"
    [id] = feature.messageId
    [layer] = "firebaseLayer"
    [coordinate]= feature.coordinate
    [properties] = feature
>
</app-vector-layer-feature>
```

The problem I'm facing with this code is that:

- Everything works as expected when the length of the array returned by `observableListFeature` is greater than 1.
- When the length of the array returned by `observableListFeature` is equals to 1, and I try to delete that item with firebase: `ngOnDestroy` is not called for that Component (`app-vector-layer-feature`)

The resumed code for `observableFeatureList`:

```
ngOnInit(){
  ...
  this.observableFeatureList = this.getFeatureListObservable();
  ...
}

getFeatureListObservable(){
  // this.db is of type AngularFireDatabase
  return this.db.list('messages')
  .map( (userList)=> {
    console.log(userList, 'UserList'); // Logs: [] UserList
                                       // But the element stills on map
                                       // because ngOnDestroy not firing
  }) //sort data by date

}
```

The pipe is just for sclicing the result array to show just a number (user input) of features in the map:

```
@Pipe({name: 'sliceObservableList'})
export class SliceObservableListPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Observable<Array<any>>, start: number = 0, end : number): Observable<Array<any>> {
    console.log(start, end, 'startend')
    return value
      .map(
          (list)=> {
              return list.slice(start, end);
          }
      )
  }
}
```

Also, here is the implementation of `app-vector-layer-feature`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges, Input, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Feature, layer, Coordinate, geom } from 'openlayers';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vector-layer-feature',
  templateUrl: './vector-layer-feature.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vector-layer-feature.component.css']
})
export class VectorLayerFeatureComponent implements OnInit {
  public instance: Feature;

  @Input() id: string|number|undefined;
  @Input() layer : layer.Vector;
  @Input() coordinate : Coordinate;
  @Input() properties : any;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.instance = new Feature();
    if (this.id !== undefined) {
      this.instance.setId(this.id);
    }

    if(this.properties){
      //console.log(this.properties, 'props')
      this.instance.setProperties(this.properties);
    }

    this.instance.setGeometry(
      new geom.Point(this.coordinate)
    );

    this.layer.getSource().addFeature(this.instance);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('FeatureDestroy')
    this.layer.getSource().removeFeature(this.instance);
    this.layer.changed();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    //console.log(changes)
    if (this.instance) {
      this.instance.setId(this.id);
      this.instance.setGeometry(
        new geom.Point(this.coordinate)
      );

      this.instance.setProperties(this.properties)
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Is the sliceObservable pipe returning a value when there's only 1 item?

Comment: @Nik, I edited my question to add more detailed information.